# Pygame: TypeError: Source objects must be a surface

Tags: python, pygame

Here are the two versions of my implementations

```
#version 1 this one works fine when I call it
class Asset(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos, path=None, paths=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos

        if path:
            # if only one image
            self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()

        else:
            self.images = paths
            self.images_index = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.images_index]


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(x_pos, y_pos))

class Player(Asset):

    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        walking = [pygame.image.load('Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_1.png'),
                   pygame.image.load('Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_2.png')]
        super().__init__(x_pos=x_pos, y_pos=y_pos, paths=walking)
        self.vert_speed = 0
        self.jumping_image = pygame.image.load(
            'Images/graphics/Player/player_jump.png')
        self.time_in_air = 0
        self.ground = y_pos
```

Whereas this one doesn't work(returns " TypeError: Source objects must be a surface")
when I call it

*The most recent call is "\pygame\sprite.py', line 546, in draw
surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites)"

```
#version 2

class Asset(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos, path=None, paths=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos

        if path:
            # if only one image
            self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()

        else:
            self.images = paths
            self.images_index = 0
            self.image = pygame.image.load(
                self.images[self.images_index]).convert_alpha()
            # The problem is right here

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(x_pos, y_pos))


class Player(Asset):

    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        walking = ['Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_1.png',
                   'Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_2.png']
        super().__init__(x_pos=x_pos, y_pos=y_pos, paths=walking)
        self.vert_speed = 0
        self.jumping_image = pygame.image.load(
            'Images/graphics/Player/player_jump.png')
        self.time_in_air = 0
        self.ground = y_pos
```

I expected these two versions to have the same outcome and cannot figure out why is the error occuring.

Could someone please explain what is the difference between these 2 versions?
I have been looking for answer but really can't find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `load` images in `pygame` and connot use the images without loading them.
You even loaded the image in `__init__` of class `Assset`, here:

```py
[...]
if path:
         # if only one image
         self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha() # <-----
[...]
```

So you should load the image in the `__init__` of class `Player`, here:

```py
[...]
walking = [pygame.image.load('Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_1.png'),
                   pygame.image.load('Images/graphics/Player/player_walk_2.png')]
[...]
```